# How to force ISO format "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sss" on the JSON output?

Tags: c#, json, datetime, asp.net-web-api2, date-format

I have an ASP .NET WebApi2 api which returns some timestamps in JSON format. The timestamps have milliseconds resolution.

Usually I got timestamps of this format which is fine `"YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sss"`

Unfortunately, if a timestamp happens to encode a date with whole second the output format is `"YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss"` (note the missing `.sss`")

How to force ISO format `"YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sss"` on the JSON output all the time?

Comment: Have you overridden any default serialization behaviour already, because I read that it would end in either a "Z" or a timezone: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#json_dates

Comment: not yet... I'm using the vanilla jsonizer which comes with the framework

Comment: Are you actually explicitly using something or just letting the web api framework do the serializing?

Comment: I'm letting the framework to serialize my objects. The "magic" happens inside the Ok(myStuffToBeReturned); method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this line to `WebApiConfig.Register`

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
       // existing stuff

       config.Formatters
            .JsonFormatter
            .SerializerSettings
            .DateFormatString = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffK";
    }
}
```

The default format is `"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.FFFFFFFK"` which gives up to 6 dp. I guessed at lowercase `f` and it appears to work.

Note the `K` is timezone (or Z for UTC) it also shows blank for unknown date types which is why you don't have anything showing there.

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini I changed from "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.FFFFFFFK" to "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.FFFFFFFZ" , and browser issue for converting datetime to local datetime solved. thanks.