# Returning the DateTime Type as a Date and Not a JSON Timestamp in Web API 2.0

Tags: c#, json, datetime, asp.net-web-api2

I'm attempting to return a date from an API method in a more friendly format i.e. DD-MM-YYYY, but I only seem to be able to get the JSON timestamp date (0000-00-00T00:00:00).

```
foreach (var todo in Todos)
{
    todo.ToDoDate = todo.ToDoDate.Date;
}
```

As you can see in the code I've tried getting round this with the `Date` function , but this still adds the T00:00:00  extension. I know that I can convert this on the front-end using JavaScript, but I'd prefer not to if I can help it.

Given that `todo.ToDoDate` is a DateTime type is there any format I can convert this to that will just give me a friendly UK date format?

Comment: You are just setting the time part to midnight with `.Date` property. You can always generate a _textual_ (aka string) representations with `.ToString` method.

Comment: Have you read the documentation about dates?https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm

Comment: I don't really recommend this.  The client and server might be in different timezones or locales with different formatting conventions.  ISO 8601 is locale-invariant and includes time offset info so avoids these problems.  See [The “right” JSON date format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10286204) and https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm

Comment: That being said, perhaps [How to force ISO format “YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sss” on the JSON output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31987050/3744182) and [How to trim in JSON the miliseconds in DateTime serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38334607/3744182) meet your needs.

Comment: Correct way _is_ parsing it in javascipt to Date object and then do whatever you want with it (such as formatting it as UK date for display in user interface).

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to string then if you want some explicit format:

```
        var myDate = new DateTime(2017, 11, 13);
        var myDateStr = myDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        //myDatestr = "13/11/2017"
```

Comment: My toDoDate property is a DateTime object so it won't hold a string - that's part of the problem

Comment: So change your controller method to return a model where this date field is a `string`. In json everything is text afterall, and you are trying to go around the conventions here anyway, it should be the receiving end that deals with how they want to format the data returned.